# No gradle build executions to visualize. Run a gradle build to see it's execution in the Gradle Executions View

Tags: java, gradle

I have imported a gradle project in Eclipse. It shows red cross on project name.

There is nothing in Gradle Tasks tab. Gradle executions Tab shows message: "There are no gradle build executions to visualize. Run a Gradle build to see its execution in the Gradle Executions View."

There is no main class in this project. What all I have to do is to run the unit tests for all methods in .java classes.

So, what should I do to build this project and remove that red cross from project name?

Answer (score -1):

I also have imported project from other machine, installed Buildship and created a debug configuration. Everything builds perfectly, no red crosses of any kind, the only thing that is anoying me is absence of Grdle Toolbar near the Console with no option of enabling it in Customize Perspective, and no output in Gradle Executions, except for the "**here are no gradle build executions to visualize**".
It also contains a suggestion to run a Gradle buid to see something. Well, of corse :( my application already runs localy and proves able to be deployed to a real web server and plugin still suggests me to run gradle build.

Comment: Please review and expand your answer, it doesn't seem to be responding to the original question